# Is there a clock difference on my CIFS mount?

Tags: linux, shell, ntp, cifs

I have a Windows share mounted on my Linux box through `cifs` and am experiencing some issues based on a time difference between machines.  For example, when working on a file in Emacs, if I try to save changes, Emacs warns me that the file has changed since it was last read in.

My guess is that when I save the file, changes get communicated back to the machine where the share is hosted and the modification time is updated based on that machine's clock.  That said, I'm not familiar with how `cifs` works.  If this is a reasonable explanation, how might I work around the issue?  If not, what could be the root issue?

Comment: do you run your own cifs/linux/windows or is this an organizations network? +1 below for ntp if this is your system, else find out how to get an admin to fix it for you. Good luck.

Comment: This is at work; trying to get them to fix the clock on the server is a battle I'd rather not fight.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I'm just a coder. You might get a better answer posting this on serverfault.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a reasonable explanation.  The solution is to synchronize the clocks using ntp.  I'm not aware of any good way to work around the problem.